# Logon failure: account currently disabled using Copy-Item

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am getting the following error when attempting to use Copy-Item in powershell;

Logon failure: account currently disabled

The powershell code;

```
Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $remotePath -Recurse -Container -Force
```

UP until yesterday, this was working fine. Today, nope. I can access the remote machine using the UNC path that it is copying the file to. I can login to the machie directly using RDP and I am in the local Admins group.

I can see nothing in the standard logs. A reboot of the target machine does nothing.

Comment: Is the remote computer on a domain? Did you try resetting the computer account from AD if so?

Comment: If another user runs the same script, on the same machine, it's fine. Based on this, not sure it's a machine problem, more something to do with my account.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli No. I use the same account on my machine here and I can also login to the target machine directly. The UNC share is also accessible, but for some reason fails within the Copy-Item.

Comment: You don't happen to have some symbolic links as part of the source folders?

Comment: No. We have a large amount of servers with the exact same config and all of these are fine. It's just this one server, using Powershell. A reboot did nothing and it's a little frustrating that  I have to logon to run my remote scripts!

Comment: Have you tried running this under a different account with the same result?

Comment: My colleague is able to run the same script remotely on the same machine with no issues.